# How not to remake pre-requisites when final target exists with Make

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

In the following Makefile, I would like make not to remake the ALL md5 files when the final file: checksums.md5 already exists:

```
SOURCEDIR := .
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.gz')
STAGES := .md5
CAT := checksums.md5
ALL := $(foreach I, $(STAGES), $(addsuffix $I, $(SOURCES)))

all : ${CAT}

%.md5: %
    md5sum $< > $@

${CAT} : ${ALL}
    cat $^ >> $@
    rm *gz.md5
```

Comment: Why do you delete `*gz.md5`? The `*gz.md5` are the requirements of `${CAT}`.

Comment: Cleaning up after I collect all the checksums into 1 file

Comment: When you create a `C` source and want to build there will be many `.o` files and after them the executable. We don't delete the object files (`.o`) because if doesn't need why should regenerate?

This is your case too. You create some mid-files to create the final file. If one `.gz` is updated its `.md5` will update and you don't need recompute ALL `.md5` to create the final `checksum.md5`. This is the reason why shouldn't delete the `*.gz.md5` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditionals. Example:

```
SOURCEDIR := .
SOURCES   := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.gz')
STAGES    := .md5
CAT       := checksums.md5
ALL       := $(foreach I,$(STAGES),$(addsuffix $(I),$(SOURCES)))

ifeq ($(wildcard $(CAT)),)

all: $(CAT)

%.md5: %
    md5sum $< > $@

$(CAT): $(ALL)
    cat $^ >> $@
    rm $(ALL)

else

all:
    @echo "Nothing to be done"

endif
```

Explanation: if `checksums.md5` exists, `$(wildcard $(CAT))` will expand as `checksums.md5` (not the empty string) and the `ifeq` conditional will instantiate what is between `else` and `endif`. If `checksums.md5` does not exist, `$(wildcard $(CAT))` will expand as the empty string and the `ifeq` conditional will instantiate what is between `ifeq` and `else`. It is a bit like if you had two different Makefiles for the two situations.

Notes:

- I suppressed useless spaces in your `foreach` call (avoid useless spaces with make, they may have an impact on its behavior).
- Do not suppress the space between `ifeq` and `($(wildcard...`, it is needed.
- I replaced curly braces (obsolete) by parentheses.
- I added parentheses to references to non-automatic variables (`$I` => `$(I)`) because it is strongly advised.
- I replaced `rm *gz.md5` by `rm $(ALL)` which seems better if you have some of your sources in sub-directories.

General remark: what you do is not inline with the make philosophy. make decides what should be done and what should not, based on the last modification time of files and a set of target-prerequisites dependency specifications. If you do not use this feature of make you should probably not use it at all. Any scripting language (bash, python, perl...) would probably be better.

If you do not want these partial md5 files, why don't you directly put the sums in `checksums.md5`? Example:

```
SOURCEDIR := .
SOURCES   := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.gz')
CAT       := checksums.md5

all: $(CAT)

$(CAT): $(SOURCES)
    md5sum $^ > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(CAT)
```

If `checksums.md5` exists and is up-to-date (more recent than the sources), nothing will be done. Else, all md5sums will be recomputed and stored in `checksums.md5`.

If your problem is to avoid recomputing md5sums of files that did not change, you need to keep track of the last time you computed them and there is no better way than keeping these intermediate md5sum files. But you can put them all in a separate directory, if you wish:

```
SOURCEDIR := .
MD5DIR    := .md5sums
SOURCES   := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.gz')
CAT       := checksums.md5
ALL       := $(addprefix $(MD5DIR)/,$(patsubst %,%.md5,$(SOURCES)))

all: $(CAT)

$(MD5DIR)/%.md5: %
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && \
    md5sum $< > $@

$(CAT): $(ALL)
    cat $^ > $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(MD5DIR) $(CAT)
```

Notes:

- Just for fun I used a different way of computing the md5sum file names (`$(ALL)`) using `addprefix` and `patsubst`.
- The `mkdir -p` in the `$(MD5DIR)/%.md5: %` recipe is needed to create the destination directory before storing the md5sum file in it.
- These destination sub-directories of `$(MD5DIR)` are needed if you have your sources also in sub-directories and some of them can have the same base name.

Comment: The reason I don't do it like md5sum $^ > S@ is that running it like make -j 8 will have no effect. The reason I use make for this is it can run multiple files simultaneously :) (Although, of course this is doable in eg. Python as well)

Comment: In your second code block I might as well run md5sum *gz > checksums.md5 from CLI

Comment: *In your second code block I might as well run md5sum *gz > checksums.md5 from CLI*: yes, absolutely, if all your source files are in the current directory and if you do not care about recomputing an up-to-date `checksums.md5`.

Comment: *The reason I don't do it like `md5sum $^ > $@` is that running it like make -j 8 will have no effect*: yes but you will also spawn only one shell instead of one per source file. Depending on the number and size of source files, the respective run-times of the 3 solutions could be surprising...

Comment: uv'd for providing a solution **and** explaining how this isn't the best idea.